# How to make a loop in Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, primes

In my attempts to learn coding, I have decided to try making a simple program in Python. I want this program to print all the primes with a value lower than 100, but I can't figure out how to loop.

Apparently, goto isn't a thing here. This is what I have so far (with pseudocode and comments where I don't know the proper functions):

```
number = 2
if number < 100
    # to be written, code determining if number is a prime. 
    if prime == True
         print(number)
        number = number + 1
        goto 2
    else:
        number = number + 1
        goto 2
else:
end
```

What can I do to make it loop instead of having to write this all out? (The prime checking code I have yet to build, and if I need help it will be in a separate question.)

Comment: I'd suggest you check the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) before ask a question here...

Comment: you will find tutorial. [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a for ... in loop

```
for number in range(1, 100):
```

This will execute with number value from 1 to 100.

And don't use neither `goto` nor `end` in any loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are trying to do in Python 3.

```
def main():
    for i in range(2,100):
        if isPrime(i):
            print ("Prime {}".format(i))
        else:
            print ("Not prime{}".format(i))

def isPrime(i):
    for b in range(2,int(i**(1/2)+1)):
        if i%b == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

To loop through all the numbers between `(x,y)` (x inclusive, y exclusive), you can do `range(x,y)`.  Or, if you want to loop through the first n numbers, you can do `range(n)`.  So, you can do

```
for i in range(100):
```

To iterate through the first 100 numbers

Comment: I am well aware that the greatest value that i will get to is 99.  He said up to 100, which means exclusive.  When I say iterate through the first 100 numbers, I am starting at 0

Comment: So there is a pre-existing function for prime checking?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  But, a number is prime if no number between 2 and the square root of the number can divide it into an integer.  So a function can be devised that uses this to tell if a number is or isn't prime.

Comment: Testing this code reveals that all integers 2-99 (inclusive) are primes. Something went wrong here.

Comment: Did you test it in a python 3 Idle? Like I said above, this is Python 3 code.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't notice the '3' bit there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner too. I think first you need ":" for loop. Then, what I know about loop are.

```
for i in range(2,100):
```

or

```
for items in itemset:      #this will iterate elements in the list
```

Answer (score -2):

this should work:

```
  while loopsecs < 5:
      print "GO DO SOMTHING productive"
      time.sleep(.2)
      loopsecs = loopsecs + .2
```